# sorting column in GridView with case insensitive

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GridView` with 4 columns and I use `EntityDataSource` for binding it's work fine, now the problem is with sorting one of the columns is for 'Job Title'

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="JOB_TITLE" HeaderText="Job Title" SortExpression="JOB_TITLE"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="etsCaseUser" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=****" 
    DefaultContainerName="****" 
    EnableFlattening="False" 
    AutoGenerateWhereClause="False"
    CommandText="select ui.[USER_ID], it.[CR_ID], it.[JOB_TITLE], it.[ADMISSION_DATE]
                from CASE_REVIEWS as it, USERS as ui where it.[SUBMITTED_BY] LIKE ui.[USER_ID]"
                OrderBy="it.[CR_ID]">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

when I click header text to sort, it show like this:

`Job Title
Doctor
Teacher 
doctor
teacher`

as you see it sort case sensitive I want to sort case Insensitive, how I can do that? any idea?

Comment: How you sort the data? You use custom sort or gridview control sort?

Comment: I do direc with sort GridView control  using `EntityDataSource` like this in GridView `AllowSorting="True" then`  `<asp:BoundField DataField="JOB_TITLE" HeaderText="Job Title" SortExpression="JOB_TITLE"></asp:BoundField>`

Comment: Sorting data and same time ignoring case sensitive could have been easily if you had used template field instead of bound field. If data is populated from code behind you could manipulate your data in your own way.

Comment: Can you give further code? How you get your data?

Comment: @Irshad I edit my code, I thinking to make Lower() but EntityDataSource not recognize any function

Comment: Are you still looking for answer for this question?